# Error partially specializing a class template to have boost::tuple as one of the parameters

Tags: templates, boost, c++11

I ran into errors while partially specializing a template with boost::tuple. The same code compiled on replacing boost::tuple with std::tuple. Here's the code condensed into the part that fails to compile.

```
template <typename... Args>
class Test;

template <typename... Args>
class Test<std::tuple<Args...>, Args...>
{
};

template <typename... Args>
class Test<boost::tuple<Args...>, Args...>
{
};

int main()
{
  int rc;

  cout<<abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(Test<boost::tuple<int, int>, int,int>).name(), 0, 0, &rc)<<endl;//Doesn't compile                                                           
  cout<<abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(Test<std::tuple<int, int>, int,int>).name(), 0, 0, &rc)<<endl;//Compiles
  return 0;
}
```

The compile error, with g++48, is

```
tuplerr.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
tuplerr.cpp:30:73: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Test<boost::tuples::tuple<int, int, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>, int, int>’
cout<<abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(Test<boost::tuple<int, int>, int,int>).name(), 0, 0, &rc)<<endl;//Doesn't compile
                                                                     ^
tuplerr.cpp:14:7: error: declaration of ‘class Test<boost::tuples::tuple<int, int, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>, int, int>’
class Test;
```

However, the specialization using std::tuple works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
// used below to create a "non-deduced context"
template<typename T>
struct Id { typedef T type; };

template <typename... Args>
class Test;

template <typename... Args>
class Test<typename Id<std::tuple<Args...>>::type, Args...>
{
};

template <typename... Args>
class Test<typename Id<boost::tuple<Args...>>::type, Args...>
{
};
```

So that the optional parameters in `boost::tuple` (which have default arguments because your boost's tuple implementation uses that to simulate variadic templates) don't make the first `Args...` contradict with the later `Args...` expansion that only has the required explicitly passed arguments.

Comment: Why does a similar specialization work when using a fixed number of arguments? For example, if `Test` was taking two template arguments and I tried to do a similar partial specialization to ensure the first argument is a `boost::tuple` wrapping around the second argument, the code compiles.

Comment: Also, the modified version fails as well with the icc14. Guess they still have a few kinks to iron out.

Answer (score 1):

`boost::tuple` doesn't work with variadic templates.

See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2709502/2524462 for a workaround.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the first claim?

Comment: Nope, but I had the chance to learn from Johannes' answer. That said ``int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int`` works with the initial code.

Comment: Interesting observation indeed.

Comment: Well from his answer, it needs to work since boost emulates variadic templates with 10 (if no other value is set by the user). 9xint fails as expected.