# Unimplemented in new gcc but implemented in old one?

Tags: gcc, c++11

The code:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

template <int N, typename Retrun_T, typename... Args_T>
Retrun_T _TupleFunctionCall(Retrun_T (*function)(Args_T... Args), std::tuple<Args_T...> Args, Args_T... RealArgs)
{
    return function(RealArgs...);
}

template <int N, typename Retrun_T, typename... Args_T, typename... Interm_Args_T>
Retrun_T _TupleFunctionCall(Retrun_T (*function)(Args_T... Args), std::tuple<Args_T...> Args, Interm_Args_T... RealArgs)
{
    return _TupleFunctionCall<N + 1>(function, Args, RealArgs..., std::get<N>(Args));
}

template <typename Retrun_T, typename... Args_T>
Retrun_T TupleFunctionCall(Retrun_T (*function)(Args_T... Args), std::tuple<Args_T...> Args)
{
    return _TupleFunctionCall<1>(function, Args, std::get<0>(Args));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << TupleFunctionCall<double, double, double>(&std::pow, std::tuple<double, double>(10, 2)) << std::endl;
}
```

compiles and runs fine in g++ 4.4.2, but produces an error in g++ 4.5.2:

> prog.cpp: In function 'Retrun_T _TupleFunctionCall(Retrun_T (*)(Args_T ...), std::tuple<_Tail ...>, Interm_Args_T ...) [with int N = 1, Retrun_T = double, Args_T = {double, double}, Interm_Args_T = {double}]':
>   prog.cpp:20:67:   instantiated from 'Retrun_T TupleFunctionCall(Retrun_T (*)(Args_T ...), std::tuple<_Elements ...>) [with Retrun_T = double, Args_T = {double, double}]'
>   prog.cpp:25:104:   instantiated from here
>   prog.cpp:14:84: **sorry, unimplemented: use of 'type_pack_expansion' in template**
>   prog.cpp:14:84: error: call of overloaded '_TupleFunctionCall(double (*&)(double,   double), std::tuple&, double&, double&)' is ambiguous
>   prog.cpp:6:10: note: candidates are: Retrun_T _TupleFunctionCall(Retrun_T (*)(Args_T ...), std::tuple<_Tail ...>, Args_T ...) [with int N = 2, Retrun_T = double, Args_T = {double, double}]
>   prog.cpp:12:10: note:                 Retrun_T _TupleFunctionCall(Retrun_T (*)(Args_T ...), std::tuple<_Tail ...>, Interm_Args_T ...) [with int N = 2, Retrun_T = double, Args_T = {double, double}, Interm_Args_T = {double, double}]

Why is it implemented in old g++ but not in new one?

Comment: Looks like this has come up a few times in G++'s lifetime.  Here's a more recent one, with some possible workarounds: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48292

Comment: Joe, do you want to turn that into an answer so we can mark it off?

Answer (score 0):

The question seems related to variadic template, you may refer to the link: [GCC error with variadic templates:  "Sorry, unimplemented: cannot expand 'Identifier...' into a fixed-length argument list"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989552/gcc-error-with-variadic-templates-sorry-unimplemented-cannot-expand-identif)