# How can I use GoogleMock in jenkins?

Tags: c++, gcc, jenkins, centos, googlemock

I installed Jenkins on a CentOS vm. Now I want to run unittests (google test) with mocks (google mock). I tried installing the frameworks like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513905/how-to-properly-setup-googletest-on-linux). (On my lubuntu machine everything runs without a problem using these steps)

When I try to build:

```
g++ -O2 -pthread -Werror -Wall -o unitTest DriveTest.cpp Drive.cpp PWM.cpp -lgtest -lgtest_main -lgmock
```

I get the following errors:

```
 make unitTest
 g++ -O2 -std=c++0x -pthread -Werror -Wall -o unitTest DriveTest.cpp Drive.cpp PWM.cpp -lgtest -lgtest_main -lgmock
 In file included from /usr/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h:75,
                  from /usr/include/gmock/gmock-generated-function-mockers.h:43,
                  from /usr/include/gmock/gmock.h:61,
                  from PWMMock.h:4,
                  from DriveTest.cpp:1:
 /usr/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1485: sorry, unimplemented: cannot expand ‘Tail ...’ into a fixed-length argument list
 /usr/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1486: error: ‘int’ is not a class type
 /usr/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1486: error: ‘ListType’ in class ‘int’ does not name a type
 /usr/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1486: error: template argument 2 is invalid
 /usr/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1486: error: expected ‘::’ before ‘ListType’
 /usr/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h: In static member function ‘static int testing::internal::MatcherList<kSize, Head,
 Tail>::BuildList(const Head&, const Tail& ...)’:
 /usr/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1493: error: ‘int’ is not a class type
 /usr/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1493: error: ‘int’ is not a class type
 /usr/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1493: error: ‘int’ is not a class type
 /usr/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1493: error: ‘BuildList’ is not a member of ‘int’
 /usr/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h: In static member function ‘static testing::Matcher<T> testing::internal::MatcherList<kSize,
 Head, Tail>::CreateMatcher(const int&)’:
 /usr/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1503: error: request for member ‘first’ in ‘matchers’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
 /usr/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1504: error: ‘int’ is not a class type
 /usr/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1504: error: ‘int’ is not a class type
 /usr/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1504: error: ‘int’ is not a class type
 /usr/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1504: error: ‘int’ is not a class type
 /usr/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1504: error: ‘int’ is not a class type
 /usr/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1504: error: ‘CreateMatcher’ is not a member of ‘int’
 ...
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of GCC is on the CentOS machine and what version of GCC is on your Lubuntu machine?

Comment: @sjdowling lubuntu has gcc version 4.8.2 and CentOS has gcc version 4.4.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though the version of GCC you have on CentOS is too old to handle these variadic templates. I would expect 4.4.7 to have them available since [the status page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) seems to indicate they should. However [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989552/gcc-error-with-variadic-templates-sorry-unimplemented-cannot-expand-identi) seems to confirm the situation.

My advice would be to upgrade the compiler using the [dev-toolset 2](http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2/) repo. This will give you access to GCC 4.8 on CentOS 6 (which by the GCC version is what I'm guessing you're using) but with a modified stdlib which means your binaries will still run using the runtime from CentOS/RedHat 5.

Comment: I upgraded gcc with dev-toolset 2. g++ -v now shows: 
     gcc version 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15) (GCC)

I can now build my project in CentOS without a problem. But Jenkins still shows the same errors?

Comment: @RIPS10 Is Jenkins using gcc 4.8 or the old 4.4? You might need to put a `source /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/enable` line at the top of your Jenkins build script to ensure the environment is switched to use the new toolchain.

Comment: Thanks, Jenkins was somehow still using the old compiler. The extra line solved my problem.